# image filtering separable matrix speed MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, imagefilter

i am currently doing a case study on the improved performance of a separable filter vs that of a square filter. I understand the mathematics behind the time complexity difference, however i have run into a problem with the real world implementation.

so basically what i have done is write a loop which implements my filter image function given by:

```
function imOut = FilterImage(imIn, kernel, boundFill, outputSize)


VkernelOffset = floor(size(kernel,1)/2);
HkernelOffset = floor(size(kernel,2)/2);


imIn = padarray(imIn, [VkernelOffset HkernelOffset], boundFill);


imInPadded = padarray(imIn, [VkernelOffset HkernelOffset], boundFill);


imOut = zeros(size(imIn));


kernelVector = reshape(kernel,1, []);
kernelVector3D = repmat(kernelVector, 1, 1, size(imIn,3)); 


for row = 1:size(imIn,1)
    Vwindow = row + size(kernel,1)-1; 
    for column = 1:size(imIn,2)
      Hwindow = column + size(kernel,2)-1;

      imInWindowVector = reshape( ... 
          imInPadded(row:Vwindow, column:Hwindow, :),1,[],size(imIn,3));

      imOut(row,column, :) = sum((imInWindowVector.*kernelVector3D),2);
    end
end


ouputSize = lower(outputSize); 


if strcmp(outputSize, 'same')  
 imOut = imOut((1+VkernelOffset):(size(imOut,1)-VkernelOffset), ...
     (1+HkernelOffset):(size(imOut,2)-HkernelOffset), : );
 elseif strcmp(outputSize, 'valid')
  imOut = imOut((1+VkernelOffset*2):(size(imOut,1)-VkernelOffset*2), ...
      (1+HkernelOffset*2):(size(imOut,2)-HkernelOffset*2), : );
 end
end
```

I wrote another script which carries out the following two sets of commands on a 740x976 greyscale image and logs their processing time:

```
for n = 1:25
   dim(n) = 6*n + 1;
   h=fspecial('gaussian',dim(n), 4);
   tic;
   Im = FilterImage(I,h,0,'full');
   tM(n) = toc;

   h1 = fspecial('gaussian', [dim(n) 1], 4);
   h2 = fspecial('gaussian', [1 dim(n)], 4);
   tic;
   It = FilterImage(I,h1,0,'full');
   Is = FilterImage(It,h2,0,'full');
   tS(n) = toc;
end
```

after plotting the respective time required i get the following result: [image: Output Plot]

My problem is, Why is the separable method slower up to kernel matrices of size 49x49, and only shows improved speed from kernel sizes of 55x55 upwards, is something wrong with my image filter code?

p.s. the image filter code was designed for 3D images to take into account colour depth, however for the speed test i am using a greyscale image converted to double using im2double.

p.s.2 so as mentioned below, for comparison i carried out the same process using MATLAB's native conv2 function, and the results where as you'd expect, and also incredibly faster... [image: same exact measure, this time using conv2 instead of FilterImage]

thanks

Comment: It my be because Matlab optimizations... Or not.

Comment: You can use profiler to inspect the timings of your code in more detail. See where the difference arises after `55x55`.

Comment: So the profiler showed that the most time hungry functions are mostly the reshape, and the sum. For some reason when using the profiler the separable approach only became faster after kernels of sizes greater than 67x67 :/ the mind boggles... Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an optimization error.
I'd use the function `conv2` instead.
Let's write a sample code:

```
mOutputImage = conv2((vFilterCoeff.' * vFilterCoeff), mInputImage);
mOutputImageSep = conv2(vFilterCoeff, vFilterCoeff.', mInputImage);
```

Try those in a loop where the length of `vFilterCoeff` (Row Vector!!!) is getting bigger.

update us what are the result now.

Comment: I tried something similar to this before posting here, implementing the exact same timing script but with conv2 instead of my FilterImage.The results were as you'd expect. The separated filter outperformed the square filter at every point starting by a small difference, to quite a substantial one, this further led me to believe that the problem was something in my own FilterImage function, which led me to post here.. i'll post the results from the conv2 timing for comparison..